# 403 Forbidden only when accessing via IP

Tags: html, apache, web

I'm having a really strange issue.  I'm embedding a video player via an object tag.  If I go to the page via the server url (ex. `127.0.0.1/stream.html` rather than `localhost/stream.html`), the page does load, but stays at a white screen. Using the web developer tool in FireFox, the console shows a `403: Forbidden Error` when grabbing the SWF player. When I use the hostname, there is no issue.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a `cross-domain.xml` set in your development environment? Meaning is the SWF player hard-coded to embed from `localhost/path/to/player.swf`, so it would load from the same hostname of `localhost` but chokes with `127.0.0.1`. Read more [on this site](http://tiffanybbrown.com/2011/10/10/html5-for-as3-developers-cross-domain-xml-and-cross-origin-resource-sharing/).

You could attempt to fix this by setting this file at the root of your `localhost` document root in a file name `cross-domain.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.macromedia.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
    <allow-access-from domain="*"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

Comment: well the SWF file is hosted on a server elsewhere, I'm just pulling it into my local server.

Comment: I found the crossdomain.xml file, and none of the entries say localhost and/or the hostname of my webserver.  i think it's worth noting that im doing this on the LAN.  when i access my web server with the external URL, it doesn't work either.  It only works when I'm on the LAN and using the internal hostname of the lamp server.